# Setting up return URL for react paypal express checkout

Tags: reactjs, paypal, checkout

I am using [react-paypal-express-checkout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paypal-express-checkout) and tried to setup the return URL in the dashboard, but this is not working. I can receive money but it does not return me to the correct page.

Can you please advise how I can add this into the react-paypal-express-checkout code?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PaypalExpressBtn from 'react-paypal-express-checkout'

export default class PaypalButton extends React.Component {

  render() {
  
const onSuccess = (payment) => { }
  
const onCancel = (data) => { }
  
const onError = (err) => { }
  
  let env = 'production';
  let currency = 'GBP';
  let total = 20
  
  const client = {
   sandbox: 'YOUR-SANDBOX-APP-ID',
  production: 'YOUR-PROD-APP-ID',
}

return (<PaypalExpressBtn env={env} client={client} currency={currency} total={total} onError={onError} onSuccess={onSuccess} onCancel={onCancel} />)

  }

}
```

Comment: No Code, no answer. lol

Comment: attached is the code

Comment: If you are receiving money, I assume it triggers `onsuccess`  func and triggers the console log as per above code. you need to Route to the page you want to, inside that function.

`browserHistory.push("/<Route>")`

Comment: Thanks so much Karun I really appreciate you helping me. I will try this tomorrow and come back to you. If anyone else has any other ideas this is greatly appreciated as well. Just one thing where does the browserhistory come from is it imported through react-router-dom?

Comment: Import { browserHistory } from "react-router"

Comment: So React Router does not have an export called browserHistory. Any ideas?

Comment: Got this working with this code in case anyone wants it i the future.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working with this code in case anyone wants it in the future.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import PaypalExpressBtn from 'react-paypal-express-checkout';

class PaypalButton extends React.Component {
    render() {  
  const onSuccess = (payment) => {
   // Congratulation, it came here means everything's fine!
              console.log("The payment was succeeded!", payment);
     // You can bind the "payment" object's value to your state or props or whatever here, please see below for sample returned data
     this.props.history.push('/routehere')
     
  }  
  
  const onCancel = (data) => {
   // User pressed "cancel" or close Paypal's popup!
   console.log('The payment was cancelled!', data);
   // You can bind the "data" object's value to your state or props or whatever here, please see below for sample returned data
  } 
  
  const onError = (err) => {
   // The main Paypal's script cannot be loaded or somethings block the loading of that script!
   console.log("Error!", err);
   // Because the Paypal's main script is loaded asynchronously from "https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"
   // => sometimes it may take about 0.5 second for everything to get set, or for the button to appear   
  }   
   
  let env = 'production'; // you can set here to 'production' for production
  let currency = 'GBP'; // or you can set this value from your props or state  
  let total = 20; // same as above, this is the total amount (based on currency) to be paid by using Paypal express checkout
  // Document on Paypal's currency code: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/
  
  const client = {
   sandbox:    'YOUR-SANDBOX-APP-ID',
   production: 'AScH9LQjnZZzeEr-Y_YzH0LS6tcmlTuJu4rYnAD2XEipTP9yekPv4bgADHpRVRQCldAObaZsAHjhv1p5',
  }
  // In order to get production's app-ID, you will have to send your app to Paypal for approval first
  // For sandbox app-ID (after logging into your developer account, please locate the "REST API apps" section, click "Create App"): 
  //   => https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_credentials/
  // For production app-ID:
  //   => https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/  
  
  // NB. You can also have many Paypal express checkout buttons on page, just pass in the correct amount and they will work!    
        return (
            <PaypalExpressBtn env={env} client={client} currency={currency} total={total} onError={onError} onSuccess={onSuccess} onCancel={onCancel} />
        );
    }
}


export default withRouter (PaypalButton);
```